# Como puedo ponerle margen a un JTextArea?

Tags: java, textarea

Lo se, es algo muy basico, pero ya he buscado en otros sitios, y otros codios.

Primero probe con el objeto **Border**, me dice que no existe el objeto, ademas, no se cual es su libreria, el codigo es este

```
Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK);
tarea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(border,  //tarea es el nombre del TextArea
               BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10)));
```

Tambien probe con el **.setMargin**, pero ese directamente no me sirve

```
tarea.setMargin( new Insets(10,10,10,10) );
```

> Soy consciente de que en Netbeans esta la opcion mas facil, pero me gustaria aprendermela de memoria sinceramente, si hay alguna libreria o un metodo, seria de gran ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Un ejemplo de como podrías añadir `padding` al cuadro de texto seria la siguiente.

```
JTextArea area = new JTextArea(18, 32);
area.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(area.getBorder(), BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5)));
```

De esta forma le estarías añadiendo un margen de 5 mm a todos sus lados.

Espero que pueda servirte.